# Is there any way to junit test a rest service that takes a MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA for file upload?

Tags: java, web-services, junit, jersey, multipartform-data

I have a restful webservice that essentailly uploads a file.  I don't have a UI built for it yet though.  I want to write a junit test that will call the service and get a file uploaded.  How would I do that?  I don't see a way to hand create the form to pass to the service.

Here is my rest service:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

    String uploadedFileLocation = "c://uploadedFiles/" + fileDetail.getFileName();

    // save it
   // saveToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

    String output = "File uploaded via Jersey based RESTFul Webservice to: " + uploadedFileLocation;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have implemented the following code and it's working fine. Let me know if you have any issues with it:

```
FormDataMultiPart form = new FormDataMultiPart();
URI uri = new File("filepath").toURI();
InputStream data =  this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("filePath");    
FormDataBodyPart fdp1 = new FormDataBodyPart("key1", uri.toString());
FormDataBodyPart fdp2 = new FormDataBodyPart("key2",data, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);

form.bodyPart(fdp1).bodyPart(fdp2); 
response = builder.post(ClientResponse.class, form);

Assert.assertEquals(response.getStatus(), Status.OK.getStatusCode());
```

Comment: I'm a newbee. Can you share the fill method please, can see where you have conifgured the API end point

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html) with JUnit.